# How to select table based on Username stored in session userdata?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have multiple tables with name matching the usernames like so
siswa1, siswa2, siswa3, ....

inside that tables theres a column named nama_guru which i used to populate a dropdown menu

What im trying to do :

load the table that match the username needed to populate the menu

What i tried so far :

Controller

```
$sesinya    = $this->session->userdata('login');
$where = $sesinya['username'];
$data = array(

            'nama_guru'         => $this->siswamodel->getIsiDropdown('username', $where),
            'variabel1'         => '',
            'variabel2'         => '',
            'variabel3'         => '',
            'saran'             => '',
            'status'            => 'baru',

        );
```

Model

```
function getIsiDropdown($where)
{
    $query = $this->db->query('select nama_guru FROM $where');
    return $query->result();
}
```

View

```
<select input type="text" name="nama_guru" value="<?php echo $nama_guru ?>" class="form-control" id="inputNama" >
<?php 
    foreach($nama_guru as $row) { 
        echo '<option value="'.$row->nama_guru.'">'.$row->nama_guru.'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: ___i have multiple tables with name matching the usernames___ Oh no!! That is a absolutely terrible way of doing anything

Comment: You need a `User` table and a `Parameters` table and a OneToMany relationship between the 2

Comment: yeah im very new here a better way to implement this is much welcome

Comment: can you explain how that works a little bit? what does parameters table contain and queries needed to use the contents?

Comment: Just a question/hint about your database itself: What is in your user tables? Does each table have only one record or do you have many? If so, why many records, is it a key-value store? If you have a table for each user, but those tables only have 1 row, then you can safely merge them all together into a single table with a User column at the start, then you can `SELECT * FROM combined WHERE user=?` to select the stuff about one user.

Comment: Use double quotes (`"`) in `$this->db->query('select nama_guru FROM $where');`

Comment: @SamRockett in those tables is "nama_guru'' row thats used for populating dropdown list which differs each user. I think i could get away with this very bad database management with a very few user count. But after extensive read about table relations and joining i have found the error in my ways, and have a better understanding of database management.

Comment: you really should follow the advice i gave in the comments of your last question. this design is a difficult way to manage everything; you are creating more work for yourself. take your time to understand database design, at least at a basic level, before proceeding. the code is only half the battle. there are plenty of tutorials, as well as other applications you can steal from.

Comment: @Alex i followed up your advice with

Comment: @Alex i followed up your advice and made a single table that contain  every questionnaire form but in unfilled state and modify its data depending on user's submission by modifying the contents with database queries instead of creating new rows every form submission. then the submitted teacher is removed from the dropdown of that particular user by changing the value in  "filled status" column to identify submitted teachers. is it in anyway an improvement or still as bad what do you think?

Comment: to be honest, i have a hard time picturing it e.g. "modifying the contents with database queries instead of creating new rows every form submission". and the 1 user per table thing, if that is indeed what you meant - as in each user has their own table - is going to get difficult to manage very quick.

Comment: what i mean is a table with columns as follow : questionnaire_id, submitter_name, teacher_name, score1, score2, score3, filled_status. questionnaire_id, submitter_name, teacher_name columns are assigned by me, while the scores and filled_status value is 0 and will be updated with the form filled by the users. to determine that a certain user submitted a questionnaire for a particular teacher my site will update the "filled_status" value to 1 with where conditions that will indicate that option will not be showed again for that student. any good?